# how to collaborate on a single document live in a text editor

Tags: javascript, php, html, sublimetext, text-editor

I would like to access a single document with multiple computers with live updates, like a google document where multiple people can write on one document and their typing is shown live. Possibly on any text editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can use AtomPair, I'm used to do pair programming with a friend, this one is the best ! https://blog.pusher.com/atom-pair/

Comment: Interesting. Is it completly free? How to run it on Ubuntu?

Comment: It' free ! Just install Atom and AtomPair, you're ready.